# RHEL 6: failing on dependencies for updating qgis rpm

Tags: rhel, sudo, upgrade, rpm

I have an rpm for a newer version of qgis than the one I currently have.

On this command: `sudo rpm --upgrade qgis-2.18.2-4.fc26.i686.rpm`, I get the errors:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
libQtCore.so.4 is needed by qgis-2.18.2-4.fc26.i686
libQtGui.so.4 is needed by qgis-2.18.2-4.fc26.i686
libQtNetwork.so.4 is needed by qgis-2.18.2-4.fc26.i686
libQtScript.so.4 is needed by qgis-2.18.2-4.fc26.i686
libQtSql.so.4 is needed by qgis-2.18.2-4.fc26.i686
libQtSvg.so.4 is needed by qgis-2.18.2-4.fc26.i686
libQtWebKit.so.4 is needed by qgis-2.18.2-4.fc26.i686
libQtXml.so.4 is needed by qgis-2.18.2-4.fc26.i686
libgdal.so.20 is needed by qgis-2.18.2-4.fc26.i686
libgeos_c.so.1 is needed by qgis-2.18.2-4.fc26.i686
libgsl.so.19 is needed by qgis-2.18.2-4.fc26.i686
libgslcblas.so.0 is needed by qgis-2.18.2-4.fc26.i686
libpq.so.5 is needed by qgis-2.18.2-4.fc26.i686
libproj.so.12 is needed by qgis-2.18.2-4.fc26.i686
libqca.so.2 is needed by qgis-2.18.2-4.fc26.i686
libqextserialport-1.2.so.1 is needed by qgis-2.18.2-4.fc26.i686
libqjson.so.0 is needed by qgis-2.18.2-4.fc26.i686
libqscintilla2.so.12 is needed by qgis-2.18.2-4.fc26.i686
libqwt.so.6 is needed by qgis-2.18.2-4.fc26.i686
libqwtpolar.so.1 is needed by qgis-2.18.2-4.fc26.i686
libspatialindex.so.4 is needed by qgis-2.18.2-4.fc26.i686
libspatialite.so.7 is needed by qgis-2.18.2-4.fc26.i686
libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.8) is needed by qgis-2.18.2-4.fc26.i686
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15) is needed by qgis-2.18.2-4.fc26.i686
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20) is needed by qgis-2.18.2-4.fc26.i686
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21) is needed by qgis-2.18.2-4.fc26.i686
qca-ossl is needed by qgis-2.18.2-4.fc26.i686
```

When doing `sudo yum update qt-devel`, I get
Package 1:qt-devel-4.6.2-28.el6_5.x86_64 already installed and latest version

How can I resolve these?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to install a Fedora 26 package built for i686 (32-bit Intel) on 64-bit RHEL 6.  That won't work due to the long list of dependencies it would pull in (as you've seen), even if you did have the appropriate FC26 repositories enabled.

Your best bet is to attempt to rebuild the package from source rpm on RHEL 6 (or CentOS 6).

Comment: Could you please give instructions/a site with steps on how to do that?

Comment: Unfortunately that can be extremely complicated.  I'm sure Google can point you to tons of documentation.

If you get extremely lucky, it might be as simple as this:

    yum install mock &&
    wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/development/26/Everything/source/tree/Packages/q/qgis-2.18.2-4.fc26.src.rpm &&
    mock -r epel-6-x86_64 rebuild qgis-2.18.2-4.fc26.src.rpm

Comment: Perhaps this is an obvious question, but if you want the most recent version of this software, why not run a Fedora system (even as a VM) instead of a 6.5-year-old server distribution?